# Optimization Opportunities: How to see which view is providing this warning?

Tags: ios

My entire app has a complex view hierarchy, which has a few different presented `UIViewControllers`. In the view debugger, I see these suggestions. When I click on the message, no corresponding view is highlighted. Right clicking the message doesn't provide any way of identifying the offending view. How can I figure out which view would benefit from optimizations?

[image: View debugger suggestion]

Comment: I'd suggest searching your code for any instances of `shadow`.

Comment: Did you configure the view debugger to display layers? If you didn't, you won't see the layer that the message is talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly is annoying that the message just talks vaguely about "the layer", and it might be worth filing an enhancement request with Apple. But you can certainly work out where the problem is, by looking at the debug navigator, where you will see the exclamation mark next to the problematic view:

[image]

Moreover, you can also find out what layer it is by choosing Editor > Show Layers. Now when you click on this message, info about the layer in question is displayed in the Attributes inspector and the Size inspector.

Comment: I'm delighted to help, but I'm not justifying this interface. I'm definitely on your side: Apple could improve the interface a _lot_. You probably tried just double-clicking on the message in the issues navigator, expecting something to appear that would show you what layer we're talking about, and that is a totally natural expectation!